# 'api' configuration does not expose dependency to the consumer of the module at compile time

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

We're trying to migrate to `gradle-4.1-rc-1` and `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9` to start working on instant apps. However we have errors in our modules configuration. Using Studio Canary 9.

We have android library module `util` which declares dependency on `dependencyA` this way:

```
api dependencyA
```

And we have another library module `lib` using `util` module

```
api project(':util')
```

But code in `lib` module cannot see dependencyA and use it. I thought that `implementation` configuration behaves this way.

Also, sometimes we are required to specify configuration for our module (when there are more than `build` and `release` build types) doing it this way:

```
api project(path: ':util', configuration: 'default')
```

Does this have impact on the issue? But standard declaration is not working.

Comment: Same here, had to revert back to canary 8. It works fine there.

Comment: same here today I updated to beta2 and started broken.